# write() not writing to device

Tags: c, linux, file-io

code:

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <linux/fs.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/param.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

void write_zero(char * file, unsigned long bytes)
{
    printf("Zeroing %s\n", file);
    unsigned int wrote = 0, total = 0;
    int fd, i, buf;
    char obj = 0x00;

    fd = open(file, O_RDWR, DEFFILEMODE);
    lseek(fd, 0, SEEK_SET);
    write(fd, &obj, bytes);
}

int main(int argc, char * * argv)
{
    int fd;
    unsigned long blocks = 0;
    char check = 0x0;

    fd = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY);
    ioctl(fd, BLKGETSIZE, &blocks);
    close(fd);

    printf("Blocks: %lu\tBytes: %lu\tGB: %.2f\n",
            blocks, blocks * 512, (double)blocks * 512.0 / (1024 * 1024 * 1024));
    do
    {
            printf("Write 0x0 to %s? [y/N] ", argv[1]);
            fflush(stdout);
    }
    while (scanf("%c", &check) < 1);
    if (check == 'y')
    {
            write_zero(argv[1], blocks * 512);
    }
}
```

I get nothing actually written to the device.. I copied my open line from the 'dd' source code, thinking maybe it was not opened right. dd can zero the device, but this program does not. Any ideas?

Comment: you are not checking the return values of your `open` and `write` function calls. You should check the return values to get a better idea of what is going on in your code

Comment: I am, I do so using gdb. I had it saving to a variable before

Comment: @phyrrus9 Can you show how this is being called and what it is displaying as output?

Comment: @PeterL. http://pastebin.com/NsQ2fLcL is my gdb output, printed both fd and wrote.

Comment: `write(fd, &obj, bytes);` obj is only one character. How large is bytes? Answer: `blocks * 512` , which is well beyond the size of obj, for most values of block > 0

Comment: bytes is passed into the function, it is the size of the device

Comment: @wildplasser are right, note that you are passing `blocks * 512` instead of `sizeof(char)`...

Comment: @TheMask blocks * 512 is the size of the device, passed into my function. sizeof(char) would make it only write a single byte

Comment: Now it will attempt to write a large part of your stack. and maybe fail.

Comment: But write a single byte is the right. One byte is the size of your data input to `write()` function: `obj` variable of `char` type.

Comment: BTW: you did not check the return value from open() and ioctl() And you don't close() after/in write_zero()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like this has been beaten to death but

```
char obj = 0x00;

fd = open(file, O_RDWR, DEFFILEMODE);
lseek(fd, 0, SEEK_SET);
write(fd, &obj, bytes);
```

Is not going to write zeros. It's going to write garbage from the stack.